# 沈く　or　沈む？ "The rock will sink."

Tags: verbs, song-lyrics

I'm analyzing the subtitles of the first episode of an anime entitled "Bleach."

During the opening there are subtitles for the theme song. There is a line that is read as such:

"物語のような石が沈く" translated as "As a story tells, the rock will sink..."

I am only aware of the verb shizuMU (沈む) not shizuKU

Is this a different form of the verb? Or is it an irregular reading of the kanji used?

Because I am aware of 滴 (雫), a suru verb and noun, but that is for a drop of water, or dripping.

Anyone have any idea? Is it just a regional accent?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fansub is incorrect. [That part](https://youtu.be/k2ThIEbisnY?t=44s) actually says 物語のような**星の雫** ([Lyrics](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-11106.html)). (雫 = dripping)

According to a dictionary, there is a verb [沈【しず】く](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/96763/m0u/) which is found in ancient Japanese documents (such as 万葉集, written more than 1000 years ago). But my IME refuses to convert しずく to 沈く, and you can safely ignore this verb.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I should have looked up the lyrics to the song...

星の雫 meaning "stardrop"....I found the lyrics on a different website.

Haha, thanks a lot! :) I will be more wary from now on...those subs were hardcoded though, the ones I have I have to load externally, soft subs. Hopefully those files are good.

ALSO! which dictionary did you use that let you know of that ancient verb? :) !

Comment: As a native speaker, I just know 沈く is not a verb used in modern Japanese. And the entry of デジタル大辞泉 (which I linked) has obviously archaic example sentences from [万葉集](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB) and [古今和歌集](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokin_Wakash%C5%AB).

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the link, thank you for your help!